# suitable Embedded system to be used for image processing and gps/gsm

Tags: embedded, hardware, fpga, beagleboard

i am working on a project, where i would like to install an embedded system in a certain location , the system is provided with a camera , the system has to perform image processing functions on the images obtained from the camera.

The system must be attached with gps and gsm modules.

i am in the process of choosing the hardware needed, i am thinking of using a beagle board or FPGA , which one is more suitable for my application ? do you recommend other boards? do you know any gsm or gps modules that can be interfaced with these modules?

Thank you

Comment: Interesting.. but unfortunately deserves a "too specific" flag and close. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your image processing algorithms are too CPU intensive I'll suggest you consider FPGAs. Otherwise, Beagle board is fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is the interface to your camera? USB / FireWire / I2C / other? If the Beagle Board supports what you need, and can handle the processing, that's probably the easiest way to go - FireWire and USB interfaces are not exactly trivial to do on an FPGA, unless you can get a board and a matching Linux distro for it, where everything is configured and working out of the box (and it's probably going to be expensive then...).

GPS modules typically connect over a simple serial connection, so that shouldn't be an issue for either solution.